# how many Web.xml for an single web app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

actually i am new to java &I am developing a Java web-application.So i want to ask..
How many **web.xml** file can be present for an single web application?
It can be more than one or it is only one for the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one place, where web.xml file will be considered by your web server (Tomcat, Jetty, WebSphera) as a deployment descriptor: only in **WEB-INF/ directory**. You can create a lot of files with this name in different directories, but only in **WEB-INF/** it will means something for your server

Answer (score 1):

I can't say about having more than one "complete" web.xml but yes you can have multiple [web-fragments](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment) of it in your application if you are using servlet3.0 .

Although this would give the illusion that you are using multiple web.xml's but in fact when the servlet container deploys your application, it will merge all the web-fragments into a single web.xml so in the end the server will still see a single web.xml for your application